# Google Script - Reference row if certain cell is not blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, javascript-objects

I have a script that hides/shows rows based on whether a checkbox in A:A is edited (ticked or not). I am currently adding rows fairly regularly, which is making me have to change the google script. A snippet of this part of the code is below.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cfg = {
    A6: {startRow: 7, endRow: 20},
    A20: {startRow: 21, endRow: 24},
    A24: {startRow: 25, endRow: 32},
  };
```

I was hoping to change the script so that it automatically looks for cells in A:A that are not blank, and assigns these values automatically.

For example, in my spreadsheet it will see that A6, A20 & A24 are not blank, so they will be inserted as the first values. It will also see that since A6 & A20 are both not blank, the startRow is 7, and the endRow is 20 etc.

This is the entire code so far - however as discussed only the first section is being looked over.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cfg = {
    A6: {startRow: 7, endRow: 20},
    A20: {startRow: 21, endRow: 24},
    A24: {startRow: 25, endRow: 32},
  };

  var activeRange = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var ranges = Object.keys(cfg);
  if (cfg[activeRange]) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues().filter(String);
values.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e[0] === true) {
        sheet.showRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      } else {
        sheet.hideRows(cfg[ranges[i]].startRow, cfg[ranges[i]].endRow - cfg[ranges[i]].startRow);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your situation, the column "A" has the values except for the checkbox. By this, when the checkboxes of "A6", "A20" and "A24" are changed, `showRows()` and `hideRows()` don't work.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues().filter(String);
```

#### To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues().filter(function(f) {return typeof f[0] === "boolean"});
```

- By this modification, the values of boolean type are retrieved.

#### Note:

- If the values of boolean type are used for the values except for the checkbox, please tell me.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for your current situation? Of course, please remove your personal information.

### Added:

If the values of boolean type are used for the values except for the checkbox, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues().filter(String);
```

#### To:

```
var temp = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1]).getValues();
var values = sheet.getRange(ranges[0] + ":" + ranges[ranges.length - 1])
  .getDataValidations()
  .map(function(f, i) {return f[0] && f[0].getCriteriaType() === SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX ? [temp[i][0]] : ""})
  .filter(String);
```